# How to extract a specific folder using IZARC (IZARCe)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, zip, extract

I want to extract a specific directory form a huge zip file (>5GB) that is somewhat corrupted because of an inevitable bad maintained build system that creates the zip.

The tools such as winrar/7Zip GUI apps have no issues extracting the files, but some command line tools such as mks unzip and 7za fails to extract from the corrupted archive.
After a lot of digging around and trying out many such command line utilities I found out that IZARC successfully extracts files from the archive.

I am running the following command:

```
IZARCe.exe -e -d -o D:\aHugeZipFile.zip -pD:\temp @"source.txt"
```

The listing file `source.txt` contains just one entry:

```
source/lib/*
```

which is the only directory in the archive, from where the contents are to be extracted.

But, it is resulting in:

```
IZArc Command Line Extraction Add-On Version 1.1 (Build: 130)
Copyright(c) 2007 Ivan Zahariev, All Rights Reserved.
http://www.izarc.org    contact@izarc.org
Archive File: aHugeZipFile.zip
WARNING: Nothing to do!
```

I have tried specifying:

```
/source/lib/*
source/lib/*
source/lib/
source/lib
*source/lib/*
```

in the listing file, all to no avail! :(
Any pointers on where the error is occurring, and how to fix the issue will be of great help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using relative or absolute paths for listfiles doesn't appear to work with IZArc. Try using wildcards such as *.*, *.doc, etc instead of paths in the listfile. Be aware that there appears to be a limitation for the folder depth that IZArc will extract to as well as a tendency to generate CRC errors when files with the same name are present in the same archive, even if they are in different directories.

I would suggest using 7-Zip command-line instead. It can recurse deeply through a file structure without error and can use relative directories and wildcards in its listfiles.

The following 7-Zip command was tested and worked perfectly.

```
7za x somearchive.zip -o"C:\Documents and Settings\me\desktop\temp_folder\test2" -ir@source.txt -aoa -scsWIN
```

the source.txt file may contain contain a combination of relative paths and/or wildcards on separate lines such as:
Output/, Folder2/, *, or *.doc.

In the command above: x (extract with full paths), -ir (include filenames, recurse subdirectories), -aoa (overide existing files without prompt), -scsWIN (set charset for list files). You may need to adjust these commands for your situation.